# Restrict Android app to an operator

Tags: android, app-store

Does anyone know if it is possible to limit the distribution of an Android app to a specific telecom operator in a specific country? for example if I want to sell my app to Verizon customers only?
Thanks!

Frederic

Answer (score 1):

Verizon has its own "sub-store" in the Android marketplace for Android apps (as far as I can tell), and they're also supposedly coming out with their own app store by the end of the year.  Here's the sign-up page:

http://promo.verizon.com/how2kit/concept_submission.aspx

In general, I believe that the only way to limit distribution of an app to a specific carrier is to use that carrier's app store (if they have one).

**Update:**  I'm not sure how you could go about restricting download access to an app available in the marketplace, but you could have your app determine the phone's carrier and not allow itself to run if it's the wrong carrier.  See:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg48701.html

Comment: Maybe Verizon was not the best example - let say a carrier which has not its own app store

Answer (score 1):

see http://groups.google.com/group/android-discuss/msg/ee236fbfb97a3837

in which poster "TreKing" writes:

> You would lose that bet =). In the
>   developer console, where you set the
>   country your app shows up in, if you
>   uncheck all countries, you get a list
>   of countries to opt in to. If you then
>   click a country, you can select the
>   carriers within that country.
>
> As usual dealing with the Developer
>   Console, this is unmarked and
>   completely non-intuitive, but it's
>   there.

Answer (score 0):

You could read out the SIM card's [IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Subscriber_Identity) ([this](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_getting_the_imsi_-_imei_sim-device_unique_ids-t446.html) may work) and analyze it.